# Why is first tab is not properly placed?

Tags: html, css

I have some problem with first tab Please check this & solve my problem I given you also fiddle :Click here to see my Problem http://jsfiddle.net/anupkaranjkar/JKQZ6/

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body { font: 0.8em Arial, sans-serif; }
        .menu { padding: 0; clear: both; }
        .menu li { display: inline; }
        .menu li a { background: #ccf; padding: 10px; float:left; 
        border-right: 1px solid #ccf; border-bottom: none; text-decoration: none; color: #000; 
        font-weight: bold;}
        .menu li.active a { background: #eef; }
        .content { float: left; clear: both; border: 1px solid #ccf; border-top: none; 
         border-left: none; background: #eef; padding: 10px 20px 20px; width: 400px; }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your .menu li to display:block

```
.menu li { display: block; }
```

here it is in working order: http://jsfiddle.net/JKQZ6/2/

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove `clear:both;` from your class called "menu". Here your updated **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JKQZ6/1/)**